Run the Wilcoxon test for each of the taxa ranks
I'm comparing a set of biological samples that are classified into two groups of interest called "Status" (1 and 0). I had the following phyloseq object:
mirl_phyloseq_final

phyloseq-class experiment-level object
otu_table() OTU Table: \[ 8229 taxa and 42 samples \]
sample_data() Sample Data: \[ 42 samples by 6 sample variables \]
tax_table() Taxonomy Table: \[ 8229 taxa by 6 taxonomic ranks \]

Then I agglomerated it by family:
mirl_phyloseq_final.family=tax_glom (mirl_phyloseq_final, taxrank="Family")

[mirl_phyloseq_final.family]
phyloseq-class experiment-level object 

otu_table() OTU Table: \[ 364 taxa and 42 samples \] 

sample_data() Sample Data: \[ 42 samples by 6 sample variables \] 

tax_table() Taxonomy Table: \[ 364 taxa by 6 taxonomic ranks \]

And then merged it with psmelt:
melted.f=psmelt (mirl_phyloseq_final.family)

So, I got a data.frame (melted.f) with the samples, the found ASVs, the abundance of each one, and the taxonomic classification agglomerated by family that looks like this:
data.frame.family
If I want to calculate the differential abundance between the two groups and run Wilcoxon for a family, I do the following:
wilcox.test (Abundance\~Status, data=melted.f\[which(melted.f$Family=="Mycoplasmataceae"),\])

And I obtain a p value.
My intention is to run the Wilcoxon test to calculate differential abundance between the two groups of samples, for all families (in a loop or something like this) and then store those p-values in a data frame with the name of each family.
Any idea how I can do it?
